# Using strfmon with cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to use the C function `strfmon` using cgo.

The example C code that works is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <monetary.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    double money = 1234.56;
    strfmon(str, 100, "%i", money);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

The Go code I've written so far is:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <monetary.h>
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := [100]C.char{}
    var money C.double = 1234.56
    C.strfmon(str, 100, "%i", money)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", str)
}
```

When I `go run main.go` I get the following error:

`./main.go:14:2: unexpected type: ...`

I believe the `...` refers to the variadic argument in `strfmon` but I'm not sure how to work around that from Go.

Comment: There is no more to the error message

Comment: The `...` refers to the variadic parameter in the C function. Take a look at `man strfmon`

Comment: Why not use x/text/currency or another third party library?

Comment: Because I can't find a package that correctly formats an amount of money for a locale. e.g. in France the Euro symbol comes after the amount, in Germany it prefixes the amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`cgo` command documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C):

> Calling variadic C functions is not supported. It is possible to circumvent this by using a C function wrapper.

And [`strfmon(3p)`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/3P/STRFMON/) is indeed a variadic function as indicated by the `...` characters in the signature:

```
ssize_t strfmon(char *restrict s, size_t maxsize,
   const char *restrict format, ...);
```

As such, you can create a wrapper function in C which has a fixed number of arguments and calls `strfmon(...)` as needed, for example:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
//
// #include <locale.h>
// #include <monetary.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
//
// size_t format_amount(char * s, size_t maxsize, char * format, double amount)
// {
//   setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
//   return strfmon(s, maxsize, format, amount);
// }
//
import "C"
import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

const SIZE = 100

func main() {
  str := C.CString(string(make([]byte, SIZE)))
  money := C.double(1234.56)
  format := C.CString("[%n]")

  C.format_amount(str, SIZE-1, format, money) // Call our wrapper here.
  fmt.Printf("OK: %s\n", C.GoString(str))
  // OK: [$1,234.56]

  C.free(unsafe.Pointer(str))
  C.free(unsafe.Pointer(format))
}
```